# select where year = specific range of years

Tags: sql, database

In my table I have a range of start and end years, example below:

```
id     start year      end year
1        2005           2007
2        2008           2012
3        2009           2012
4        1998           1999
5        2005           2006
```

I want to select only those that are between the years 2005 and 2006

I'm sure this is very simple to someone else but I cannot get my head around it!

**EDIT :**

Just seen the answers and realised how dumb this question was! For some reason I was thinking that doing that was wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   [start year] <= 2006 
        and 2005 <= [end year]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use simple clause with >= <=

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `start_year`>= 2005 AND `end_year` <= 2006
```

Comment: That would miss the `2000 - 2010` range

Comment: but he wants between the years 2005 and 2006 so 2000 and 2010 are not in this group are they?

Comment: You're right that the question is open to interpretation.  With your condition, only row 5 would match.